# Avoid unnecessary multiple identical calls when nesting event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a setting where I am using nested jQuery [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) event handlers, and this results in unnecessarily duplicated function calls.

I would like to do the following:

- get user input, which will be passed to an external API, returning a list of results.
- populate a dropdown menu with those results, and automatically select the first one, and use it to do something.
- watch the dropdown for changes, and if the user selects a new option from the list, use that instead.

The following snippet does what I want, however, as you can see, `console.log()` is called multiple times (where the number of times equals the number of times that the `myInput` text's `input` handler was triggered).  *[To see this, type some number of characters in the input box, and select an option from the dropdown.  The console will log the option you chose a number of times equal to the number of characters you input]*
How can I avoid this ever-growing number of identical calls?

```js
function setOptions(prefix) {
  // in actual setting, pages = externalAPI(prefix)
  pages = [prefix + "(a)", prefix + "(b)", prefix + "(c)"]
  $('#mySelector').html(
    pages.map(function(page, i) {
      return $("<option />").val(i).text(i + ': ' + page)
    }))
  return pages;
};

function setSelected(val) {$('#mySelected').html(val)};

$(function() {
  $('#myInput').on('input', function() {
    let options = setOptions($(this).val())
    setSelected(options[0]);
    $('#mySelector').on('change', function(e) {
      console.log(this.value);
      setSelected(options[this.value]);
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Input a prefix, then select an option.</p>
<input type="text" id="myInput"></input>
<select id="mySelector"></select>
<p>selected: <span id="mySelected">&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace

```js
$('#mySelector').on( ... )
```

with

```js
$('#mySelector').off().on( ... )
```

to cancel all event handlers for element when creating new one.

Below is your snippet modified with my fix.

```js
function setOptions(prefix) {
  // in actual setting, pages = externalAPI(prefix)
  pages = [prefix + "(a)", prefix + "(b)", prefix + "(c)"]
  $('#mySelector').html(
    pages.map(function(page, i) {
      return $("<option />").val(i).text(i + ': ' + page)
    }))
  return pages;
};

function setSelected(val) {$('#mySelected').html(val)};

$(function() {
  $('#myInput').on('input', function() {
    let options = setOptions($(this).val())
    setSelected(options[0]);
    $('#mySelector').off().on('change', function(e) {
      console.log(this.value);
      setSelected(options[this.value]);
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Input a prefix, then select an option.</p>
<input type="text" id="myInput"></input>
<select id="mySelector"></select>
<p>selected: <span id="mySelected">&nbsp;</span></p>
```